# Conditional logic based on colour in Less

Tags: css, less, mixins

I have the following mixin using Less that takes the input colour and shades a few boxes etc. I use a lightened version of the colour for borders but sometimes I find that my colour is too light and so ends up as white. What I'd like to do is check if the lightened colour is white (or 80%) and make it just the default colour being passed in. I've put my when statement in to switch between the colours but I get a  NameError variable @section-base-color is undefined. I'm not sure to how to get this to work on a parameter passed in.

```
.sectionstyles(@section-base-color) {
    .product-single {

        & when (lightness(lighten(@section-base-color, 45%)) > 80%) {
            border: 1px solid @section-base-color;

        }
        & when (lightness(lighten(@section-base-color, 45%)) <= 80%) {
            border: 1px solid lighten(@section-base-color, 45%);            }
        .clearfix;
        a {
            margin-top: 0;
            color: @section-base-color;

            h2 {
                margin: 0 (-@padding-base-horizontal);
                padding: @padding-base-horizontal;
                color: @section-base-color;
            }
            p {
                color: @text-color;
            }
            &:hover, &:focus {
                color: #FFF;
                h2 {
                    background-color: @section-base-color;
                    color: #FFF;
                }

            }
        }

    } 
}
```

For reference, the function is lightness, not lightenless. This was causing me a problem.

Comment: This may be a version issue. Your code works for me using LESS 1.7 (on http://lesstester.com/).

Comment: hmm WinLess has LESS.js 1.6 - will try an update.

Comment: Yes, I think that is your issue. Using 1.6 at http://less2css.org/ I get the same error you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1: Upgrade LESS

Stick with what you have, and upgrade to LESS 1.7.

### Option 2: Explicitly set variable inside mixin

This works for LESS 1.6:

```
.sectionstyles(@section-base-color-input) {
    @section-base-color: @section-base-color-input;
    etc... (rest of code the same)
```

There seems to be a bug in the `& when` syntax with respect to looking at mixin parameters in 1.6, but if you use that parameter to explicitly set a local variable inside the mixin, that variable is accessible as expected.

Comment: Hi Scott, this is how I've fixed it. I'm currently running WinLess and the update process for 1.6 to 1.7 is broken. If I overwrite the less files it breaks Winless and if I use NPM it stops outputting my CSS files. Didn't have time to resolve it so just tweaked my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A slightly offtopic answer (@ScottS already answered the actual question), just a few tips/hints on "conditional colour logic" to meet the subject title.

#### Alt. solution #1: Contrast.

When it comes to colour lightness, Less has the [contrast](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-contrast) function to conditionally select one of two colour values based on a third colour luma. E.g.:

```
.sectionstyles(@base-color) {
    .product-single {
        border: 1px solid
            contrast(@base-color, @base-color, 
                lighten(@base-color, 45%), 10%);

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Note that `contrast` internally uses [`luma`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-channel-luma) not `lightness` so this snippet is not exactly equal to your initial code (the `10%` threshold value I used above roughly resembles `80%` lightness threshold for a gray shades).

#### Tip #1: Mixin parameter names.

Usually you don't have to use so specific "fully qualified" names for a mixin parameters. Since `@section-base-color` is the parameter of the `.sectionstyles` mixin and not a global variable, the `section` prefix is somewhat redundant there. Just `@base-color` (as I used above) in context of `.sectionstyles` is naturally supposed to mean `section styles base color`. We don't have to be so verbose when not necessary.

#### Tip #2: "Lightness of Lighten".

`lightness(lighten(@section-base-color, 45%)) > 80%` can be simplified to `lightness(@section-base-color) > 35%` (where `35%` is `80% - 45%`, i.e. an arithmetic addition of the lightness channel is what the `lighten` does).

#### Alt. solution #2: Conditional mixins.

Though `& when` may be seen as most obvious and less verbose method when compared to conditional mixins in general, it's not always true in many cases:

```
.sectionstyles(@base-color) {
    .product-single {

        border: 1px solid @border-color;

        .-() {@border-color: lighten(@base-color, 45%)} .-();
        .-() when (lightness(@base-color) > 35%) {
            @border-color: @base-color;
        }

        // etc.
    }
}
```

Conditional mixin beats conditional `&` here as even while still being quite verbose we don't need to repeat `border: ...`, `lightness(...)` and `80%` twice (i.e. finishing with more maintainable code).

Comment: Excellent answer (I've accepted Scott's as it was most relevant to the question. I'd seen the contrast function) and might have a play with it as I think it achieves what I'm looking to do.